# return javascript variable from inside callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to get client.get to return the reply value so it can be used globally.It keeps saying undefined.any suggestions

```
var redis = require("redis");
var websocket= require("websocket");
var valuewanted;
websocket.on('message', function(data) {

 if (data.type == "purchase" && data.price > 0) {

  console.log("==========================================================");
  console.log(data );
  console.log("==========================================================");

client.get(p1, function(err, reply) {
        var valuewanted = reply;
            console.log(reply);
        });  
});
```

the console.log logs the value but if i try to log valuewanted it doesnt work.

Comment: You redefine `var valuewanted` inside `get` callback so it is *different* `valuewanted` which is local to the function.

Comment: what would be the right way to do it ?

Comment: Check if function(err, reply) should (is expected to) return a value.

Comment: remove `var`. Just `valuewanted = reply;`. In any case you can operate it only inside `callback`. Do not expect `return valuewanted;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `var` within the client.get function:

```
client.get(p1, function(err, reply) {
  // valuewanted already defined above
  valuewanted = reply;
  console.log(reply);
});
```

If you use var within a function, it becomes scope-blocked to that function.

From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution
>   context, which is either **the enclosing function** or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

In this case, using `var` within that function redefines it within that function, and its scope becomes "the enclosing function".  Hope this helps.